# Highcharts stealing click inside an angular directive

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using highcharts inside of an angular directive and i need to be able to click on the entire div but the chart inside the div isn't doing anything when i click on it.

I've tried putting a clear div with absolute positioning over the highcharts div but still nothing happens when I click inside the chart area.

I'd prefer not to pass the click functionality to highcharts as it would add extra dependencies. I feel like there should be some sort of highcharts property for this but I'm not able to find it.

Anyways here is the code..

Directive Template (note the commented out clear div right above the chart area):

```
<div class="key-metric" ng-click="makeMetricInFocus($event)">

<!--<div class="overlay" ng-click="makeMetricInFocus()"></div>-->
<div id="{{metricData.metricName}}" class="key-metric-chart">
</div>
```

The make metricInFocus function is located in the directive, it just updates the model.

Here is the code for the highChart (it's called through the directive):

```
headGraphService.sparkLine = function (metricInfo, chartContainer) {
            var container = $('#' + chartContainer);
            if (container.highcharts()) {
                container.highcharts().destroy();
            }
            $timeout(function () {
                new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: chartContainer,
                        margin: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        // maxPadding: 0,
                        // minPadding: 0,
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        endOnTick: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            enableMouseTracking: false,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            shadow: false
                        },
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        line: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        color: metricInfo.chartingColors.summaryLine,
                        type: 'line',
                        data: metricInfo.data
                    }],
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                })
            }, 500)
```

Comment: You could find some info for using AngularJS with Highcharts on the Highcharts official article - http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js - maybe this will be helpful for you. Also, you could capture chart's click event through Highcharts API - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with using highCharts and Angular.  That's not the issue.  The problem is the click event getting lost over the highCharts chart.  I believe this to be a propagation issue but I cannot figure it out.